# Python list of list count elements

Tags: python, list

Hello I am trying to count all the elements in a list of lists.
For example

```
a = [[1,2],[3,4],[10,3,8]]
```

I want to return:

```
7
```

I tried count and size with no luck.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: For multiple-levels deep `len(str(a).strip('[],').split(','))`  Edit I tried here: http://ideone.com/gzpt65

Comment: for your list: http://ideone.com/U1f93P

Answer (score 8):

```
a = [[1,2],[3,4],[10,3,8]]
print(sum(map(len, a)))
```

**Output**

```
7
```

This can be written as a generator expression, like this

```
print(sum(len(item) for item in a))
```

The simplest method which would work even for multilevel nested lists, goes like this

```
def get_size(current_item):
    if isinstance(current_item, list):
        return sum(get_size(item) for item in current_item)
    else:
        return 1

a = [[1,2],[3,4],[10,3,8],[[1, 2, 3], [2, 3]]]
print get_size(a)    # 12
```

Comment: Note that this won't work if your lists are multiple-levels deep. In that case you'll need to use a recursive solution.

Comment: @adsmith Agreed, but OP says, just `list of lists`

Comment: In fact, since the questioner wants to count the elements in a list of lists, then recursing through any number of levels of list would give the wrong answer in the case where the lists are more levels deep. It's a question of whether you want the answer for `[[[1,2]]]` to be 1 (the number of elements in the list-of-lists: this one element happens to be a list) or 2 (the number of elements at any level of nested lists).

Comment: @SteveJessop Yes but in my experience, people will often over-simplify their questions in order to create a short complete example, so I wanted to drop a note in case OP comes back and says "No that's giving me the wrong result" when he applies it to his 300-element list of lists with lists.

Comment: @adsmith That's true! My list is multiple-levels deep so this is not working. I should have mentioned that. Any idea how to do this recursively?

Comment: I posted a stupid trick :) would like to share with you check comment to question,  Edit I like your second code piece

Comment: @user1855165 my answer gives the recursive solution.

Comment: @thefourtheye Thank you for your update. I felt bad for having a correct answer that I essentially just "guessed," plus your recursion is much prettier than mine :)

Comment: @thefourtheye Thanks! How about ndarray (if I am using numpy)? Is it the same?

Comment: @user1855165 I am sorry :( I don't know numpy :'(

Answer (score 1):

For academic purposes, if your list is more than one level deep (e.g. `[ [1,2,3], [4,5,[6,7,8]]]`, one of your elements contains a list) you'll want to do something like:

```
def count_elements(target):
    count = 0
    for element in target:
        if type(element) is list:
            count += count_elements(element)
        else:
            count += 1
    return count
```

But the problem as described by OP is easier-solved with one of the other answers. Just mentioning that those solutions are not easily scalable.

Answer (score 0):

You can either sum the lengths (like @thefourtheye suggested), or iterate over all elements, and count:

```
sum(len(b) for b in a)
sum(1 for b in a for c in b)
```

The first way is clearly better, but the second is nice for demonstrating some things you can do with list comprehensions, and would also work on a more general structure,  of *iterable of iterables* (which do not have `__len__` defined).

Comment: For the iterable of iterables you probably want to replace the use of `len` with something like `def mylen(iterable): try: return len(iterable) except TypeError: return sum(1 for x in iterable)`. That is, do it fast for iterables where that's possible, slow otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

```
def myLen(L):
    if not L:
        return 0
    elif not isinstance(L[0], list):
        return 1 + myLen(L[1:])
    else:
        return myLen(L[0]) + myLen(L[1:])
```

Output:

```
>>> myLen([[1,2],[3,4],[10,3,8]])
7
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list_count = 0

mainList = [[1,2],[3,4],[10,3,8]]
for inner_list in mainList:
  list_count += len(inner_list)

print(list_count)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can flatten that list and then use `len()` on the flattened list:

a = [[1,2],[3,4],[10,3,8]]

flattened_a = [item for sublist in a for item in sublist]

len(flattened_a)